# Hover causes image to dissappear

Tags: css, reactjs, sass

I'm doing a React & Sass tutorial and the last image on the slider/carousel disappears whenever I hover on an image.

The issue seems to stem from `position: absolute`in `&:hover`. If I remove this, the last image appears whenever I hover on an image. I need to include this line so that the hover appears at the correct position.

The .scss for the slider:

```
.list {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 10px;

  .listTitle {
    color: white;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 500;
    margin-left: 50px;
  }

  .wrapper {
    position: relative;
    .sliderArrow {
      width: 50px;
      height: 100%;
      background-color: rgb(22, 22, 22, 0.5);
      color: white;
      position: absolute;
      z-index: 99;
      top: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      margin: auto;
      cursor: pointer;

      &.left {
        left: 0;
      }

      &.right {
        right: 0;
      }
    }
    .container {
      margin-left: 50px;
      display: flex;
      margin-top: 10px;
      width: max-content;
      transform: translateX(0px);
      transition: all 1s ease;
    }
  }
}
```

The .scss for the individual items within the slider:

```
.listItem {
  width: 225px;
  height: 120px;
  background-color: var(--main-color);
  margin-right: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: white;

  img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
  }
  &:hover{
    width: 325px;
    height: 300px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -150px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.07);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.07);
    border-radius: 5px;

    img {
      height: 140px;
    }
  }
}
```

Screenshots:

[image]

[image: image disappear]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just realized what's going on. When I hover, the item that is being hovered is taken out of the list and the rest of the items are pushed inwards, it wasn't actually missing. It would have been more obvious had I used different images for each item.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use margin properties to set image to proper position coz position:Absolute will shift the image to move according to the page and top : 150px makes the image move beneath the main image(Cover Image)